# Python 3: optional types: I need to specify type for True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

For example:

`def foo(x: bool=True)`

maybe enough: `def foo(x=True)`?

PyCharm still can understand that type is `bool`.

Comment: `def foo(x=True)` is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before type hinting was added to the Python language, IDE's already inferred types from the codebase based on things like default values.

So PyCharm can infer, from the default value `True` for the parameter `x`, that `x` should be a boolean. That doesn't mean that that is an actual type hint however. Plenty of tools that support type hint checking do not use type inference.

If you want your code to interoperate with other type hint checkers such as `mypy`, you need to explicitly state the type:

```
def foo(x: bool=True):
    # ...
```

Comment: Why `mypy` do not infer type from `True`?

Comment: Because setting a default value does not mean the function won't accept other types too.

Comment: You can thing about `x = None` type default values. It does not mean that `x` should be set only to `NoneType`.

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov: Note that `x: t=None` (so with a typehint `t`) implies that `Optional[t]` is used. This is a special case.